# Sending a Email using smtp server in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I would like to send email using SMTP server through .net Core.
Please explain

Comment: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/how-to-send-emails-in-asp-net-core-1-0

Answer (score 19):

Through the .net core framework, you can't as it stands right now.

At the time of writing .net core version 1.1 implements the .net standard of 1.6. At that point in time, System.Net.Mail had not been ported. But as you can see by this pull request : https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/12416 . It looks it's going to make it into .net Standard 2.0 (Which will likely then be implemented in the next version of .net core).

In the meantime, it seems like everyone is using the library MailKit (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) which works pretty well!

Comment: For the record: Even after this PR has been merged, the official API docs recommend using MailKit and MimeKit instead of the SMTPClient API