# Using System.Net.Mail to email results from MVC form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-core, system.net.mail

I'm trying to email the results from a form in my MVC application but when I try to add `using System.Net.Mail` I get the message that Mail isn't found in the namespace of System.Net.

I tried looking for the dll to add as a reference, but I cannot find the dlls for System, System.Net or System.Net.Mail.  However it has no problem with `using System.Net` but that doesn't get me access to `MailMessage()` or `SmtpClient`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and the latest versions of MVC.  Does anyone know where to find or how to install these dll's or if there's a better way to email form results I'd love to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using .NET core or .NET Framework?

Comment: I'm using .Net core

Comment: System.Net.Mail is not yet ported to .net core version 1.1. This is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583858/sending-a-email-using-smtp-server-in-net-core

Comment: So are my options to just use the mail kit as described in that post or switch to using framework?  What's the difference, pros and cons, of course vs framework?

Comment: @JoeHigley: If you run it on Windows, there are no downsides. Linux/MacOS. As you may have heard, there is no native .NET Framework there. Just mono which is not a 100% replacement for .NET Framework

Comment: Mail sending is not supported in asp.net core mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the credit for this answer should go to Scotty for his comment above:

### System.Net.Mail is not yet ported to .net core version 1.1. This is discussed here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/41583858/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583858/sending-a-email-using-smtp-server-in-net-core) – Scotty May 1 at 4:05

Following that the answer is that System.Net.Mail is not ported into .net core yet but might be making it's way with .net core 2.0.  In the meantime the way to get around this is a nice package called MailKit.  Just install that using the package manager and then look to the Readme for examples of how to use it.

Thanks again and a shout out to @Scotty